# SQLite - Update a column based on values from another table's columns

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to update **Record1**'s **ID** to **Record2**'s **ID** when:

- the **Name** is the same in both tables, and
- **Weight** is greater in **Record2**.

**Record1**

```
| ID | Weight | Name |
|----|--------|------|
|  1 |     10 |    a |
|  2 |     10 |    b |
|  3 |     10 |    c |
```

**Record2**

```
| ID | Weight | Name |
|----|--------|------|
|  4 |     20 |    a |
|  5 |     20 |    b |
|  6 |     20 |    c |
```

I have tried the following SQLite query:

```
update record1
set id = 
  (select record2.id 
   from record2,record1 
   where record1.name=record2.name 
   and record1.weight<record2.weight)
```

Using the above query **Record1**'s **ID** is updated to 4 for all records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing `SELECT ...record1` introduces a new instance of the `record1`  table that hides the outer one.

To be able to refer to the current row in the outer query, just remove `table1` from the FROM clause:

```
UPDATE record1
SET id = (SELECT record2.id 
          FROM record2
          WHERE record1.name   = record2.name 
            AND record1.weight < record2.weight);
```